# How to get Magento Currency Selector as a pop-up window

Tags: template, currency, header, popup

The Currency Selector is already there in header. But I would like to have it as a pop-up window, where customers can choose their desired currency.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahul,It can easy possible. Make call pop on this  just call the below code:

```
    <?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock("directory/currency")
->setName("pop_currency")->setTemplate("directory/currency.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks a ton for your Reply! But, could you please tell me where to add this code and how to make use of it?

Comment: create pop ownself... then call my code...